# When we say "עַל צִיצִת הַכָּנָף" at which point do we kiss the tzitzis?

Tags: minhag, tzitzis, shema, kissing

When we say Krias Shema, the widespread custom (referred to in OC 24 (4) Rema), is to kiss the tzitzis when we say the word, “צִיצִת”.

When we come to the words, עַל צִיצִת הַכָּנָף (which [Singer](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/spb/spb15.htm) translates as “upon the fringe of each corner”), to kiss at the word צִיצִת interrupts between the words צִיצִת and כָּנָף which belong together. I think it is better to kiss after the word כָּנָף.

The problem with my thought is that in OC 61(20) it says one must avoid run-ins of words where one ends in the letter that begins the next and gives as one example הַכָּנָף פְּתִיל . If we stopped to kiss the tzitzis after the word הַכָּנָף (as I suggest) there would be no need for the Shulchan Oruch to gives us this din.

Can anyone provide evidence either way on my idea please?

This question [Kissing Tzitzis during Shema](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8817/kissing-tzitzis-during-shema) is related.

Comment: Don't bring proof from Hakanaf-Petil. That is the the din as brought down in a braita in the gemara. The minhag to kiss is much later. The shulchan aruch could be quoting the din as it is in the gemara without intending to account for later minhagim which are in no way required (unlike separating between different similar sounds which are required).

Comment: I've always been taught to kiss after Kanaf.

Comment: I don't understand: You say the _Rama_ says to kiss directly after _tzitzis_. You say the _SA_ says to pause between _hakanaf_ and _p'sil_. What basis do you have for thinking it might possibly be best to kiss after _hakanaf_?

Comment: If the Beith Yosef is the one who says not to kiss them (as established by one of the answers to the question you linked) then it makes perfect sense for Shu"'A to say you need to pause so the words don't run together. There is no contradiction.

Comment: @msh210 The trop.

Comment: @DoubleAA, no, (no offense, but) I was addressing the asker, inviting him to add into his question his reasons for asking. (Anyway, while the trop puts _tzitzis_ and _hakanaf_ together, I don't see what that has to do with kissing.)

Comment: @msh210 If you ask most kids what the words mean they'll say something like: "And you should put on the tzitzit; the corner has a blue string!" Kissing is nice as chibuv mitzva, but not at the expense of another mitzva. People often forget that switching connective and pausal trop can change the meaning too.

Comment: I would take out the Rema.  He makes to reference to the word tzitzis.  Replace with someone who specifically references this minhag.

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?mfid=108000&rid=479 says to kiss after the whole phrase על ציצת הכנף פתיל תכלת

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Chabad Minhag [HaYom Yom Sivan 22](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/5803/jewish/Sivan-22.htm)

Kiss the tzitzit six times, at the words tzitzit, tzitzit, l'tzitzit, emet, kayemet and la'ad."

Whether or not words next to those words complete the sentence does not seem to be relevant.